# Create an offline version of web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, offline

Question :
Where to start to write an application which can work without internet connection? Exactly like [this](https://learningequality.org/ka-lite/)

Explanation :
Say we have an web application which is already deployed. Since internet is not great in INDIA, I would like to create an offline version of same web application which users/people can access without internet as well. I want them to experience similar stuff of web interface without much of the changes.

One idea that came to my mind is to create a tar ball of contents of application and ship to the people/users. Users will have to use that tar ball to install/configure on their machine so that they can use it. Contents of tar ball is also debatable that what should I enclose in that tar ball. Apache, Technology stack etc etc.

I will be happy to write more in case I have not written precisely. My question is not related to any technology stack but this might be of interest to everyone. Since I am not sure which is the right tag to append here, can anybody from stackoverflow team help to tag right tag. :)

My application is actually in RoR. So, Tagging ruby on rails community. May be they can help here?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your web application contains only flat files (HTML, CSS, JS, text data, etc.) and does not depend on any components that need to be installed, then you can simply distribute those files in an archive (`.zip` will be more cross-platform-friendly) and the user could open the application by opening the front page in a browser. To make it better for the user, a small application which invokes the user's browser with the local URI should also be included.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ohh, I should have mentioned that my application is not static. It generate pages dynamically based on the database.